# Weird behaviour with prettier in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, prettier

So Prettier is behaving quite weirdly for me. I have this simplified interface in a language called solidity:

```
interface Token {
  function getTotalSupply(address _market, TokenType _tokenType) external view returns (uint256);
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount, TokenType _tokenType) external;
}
```

After formatting it gets formatted to this:

```
interface Token {
  function getTotalSupply(address _market, TokenType _tokenType) external view returns (uint256);

  function mint(
    address _to,
    uint256 _amount,
    TokenType _tokenType
  ) external;
}
```

I want both functions to stay on one line. The printWidth option does not seem to be the issue here, as the first function is actually longer than the second one and does not line break. The difference seems to be that the second function has more arguments and that every function with more than 2 arguments gets split up. Here is my .prettierrc

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.sol",
      "options": {
        "printWidth": 160,
        "tabWidth": 4,
        "useTabs": false,
        "singleQuote": false,
        "bracketSpacing": false,
        "explicitTypes": "always"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me. Do you have your .Prettierrc file in the root, and did you reload/restart after setting it up?

Comment: the file is in root, settings like _tabWidth_ or _useTabs_ work quite fine, except for _printWidth_ which is ignored and results in this weird behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't seem too fine for me though, first of all I don't think a line break should be added between the interface declarations and also I don't think the `mint` function should be broken up into multiple lines, as it's only 80 characters long

Comment: I meant your .Prettierrc seemed fine to me :)